# How can I use a vpn and not worry about some websites running active content revealing my real IP?

Tags: privacy, vpn, anonymity

I think using https prevents that, but not all sites can do https.

Answer (score 2):

It is not quite clear what kind of "active content revealing my real IP" you are referring to but my guess is that you mean WebRTC which can be used to determine the public visible IP address. In this case use a browser which has no support for WebRTC or has disabled it. The TOR browser is a good choice in this regard.

Apart from that various other information leaks might reveal your public IP address, depending on the type and setup of VPN you are using. If for example your are only using some application level "VPN" (like the one built into the Opera browser) your IP address might be revealed by applications not using this "VPN", by DNS lookups or simply because IPv6 traffic is not done through the VPN.

Comment: Sorry I was referring to Ajax/Media/websockets etc. leaking the real IP address. Are they different from webRTC?

Comment: @user118832: how does these leak the real IP address when using a VPN?

Comment: I don't exactly know but I guess something like the answer no.2 in this thread?: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/40023/how-to-expose-a-clients-real-ip-address

Comment: @user118832: if you have a closer look at this response the author even states that he has no sources for this claims and a comment really doubted that this is possible. I too doubt that this is possible so please give some usable sources and not some unproven claims.

Answer (score 0):

Whether the content is a page you open directly or through active JavaScript (or other front-end system) is irrelevant.  If your system is properly configured, it will use the VPN as its default gateway and it won't matter what application or protocol uses the connection.

The only thing that will commonly happen when setting up a VPN is that the DNS requests may still go directly to your ISP.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not really understanding how this is related to my question? Maybe I explained it wrong. What's irrelevant? Active contents run by the websites I visit while I'm connected to vpn?

Comment: I've edited it to make it a bit more obvious to you.  I basically meant that the type of access (direct or dynamic) is irrelevant to the VPN hiding what you do.

Comment: I use [SoftEther VPN Client](https://www.softether.org/) to avoid being banned on a specific website that blocks based on IP address. Proxies do not block things such as action script that runs locally and can still query your IP. However as long as you get assigned an address by the DHCP service and use a virtual adapter they should only see the address you were assigned by the VPN host network.